# Что делать с ошибкой java: illegal start of expression?

Tags: java

Вот библиотеки и строка на которой ошибка:

```
package com.portside.buildffa.utils;

import com.portside.buildffa.inventorysort.InventorySort;
import com.portside.buildffa.main.BuildFFA;
import org.bukkit.Color;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;



public static void Enterhaken(Inventory player) {
            player.clear();
            player.setItem(0, ItemUtils.buildItemenchantment(Material.GOLD_SWORD, 1, 0, "§eМеч", Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 1));
            player.setItem(1, ItemUtils.createItem(Material.FISHING_ROD, 1, (short) 0, "§eAngel"));
            player.setItem(2, ItemUtils.buildItemenchantment(Material.STICK, 1, 0, "§eВолшебная палочка", Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 1));
            player.setItem(3, ItemUtils.createItem(Material.LADDER, 3, (short) 0, "§eЛестница"));
            player.setItem(4, ItemUtils.createItem(Material.SANDSTONE, 64, (short) 0, "§eБлоки"));
            player.setItem(5, ItemUtils.createItem(Material.SANDSTONE, 64, (short) 0, "§eБлоки"));
            player.setItem(6, ItemUtils.createItem(Material.SANDSTONE, 64, (short) 0, "§eБлоки"));
            player.setItem(7, ItemUtils.createItem(Material.SANDSTONE, 64, (short) 0, "§eБлоки"));
            player.setItem(8, ItemUtils.createItem(Material.ENDER_PEARL, 1, (short) 0, "§eЭндер Пёрл"));
        }
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: А где название класса в вашем коде?  Почему он начинается с определения статического метода?

Comment: Ошибки нужно находить и исправлять, а в идеале - не допускать. "... и строка на которой ошибка" - здесь много строк...

Answer (score 0):

В языке Java нельзя создавать методы вне класса. Поместите ваш метод в класс, например, с именем `Main`. Имя класса должно соответствовать имени файла.

К примеру, файл `Main.java`:

```java
package ...;

import ...;

public class Main {
    
    public static void enterhaken(Inventory player) {
        // ваш код
    }
    
}
```

Кроме этого, возьмите на заметку, что в языке Java принято именовать классы с заглавной буквы, а методы — с маленькой буквы.